# play mp3 javascript

Tags: javascript, mp3

I am new with programming, how do play music in <strike>Java program</strike> Javascript? <strike>make like winamp</strike> A program that looks like Winamp.

Comment: i need script from Java how play mp3 simple. Efficiency, Usability

Comment: I did pretty much this exact thing. Took me a few years: https://github.com/captbaritone/webamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably much too difficult for your first program. The first thing you need to know is Java is not the same as Javascript. So I'd go and learn some Java first (try [the Sun tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), they are very good), and then maybe look at this information:[Java Zoom article](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/08/11/javasound-mp3.html) . Good luck!

Comment: ty!! but I need script from Java simpple, no tutorials !!

Comment: Did you even follow the link to the "Java Zoom" article? When I see "no tutorials" I read "please do my job for me."

Comment: is not this forum for do job for ? i like do job but had no time to do ! please help !

Comment: This is not a place to hire or ask people to do your work. Try http://careers.stackoverflow.com or some other job sites.